# converting a vector loop to a for loop because of memory limitations

Tags: matlab, octave, sox

I have a piece of Octave / Matlab code that I received a lot of help from Andy and the group with.  The issue i’m running into now is not enough memory to make signals that are longer in duration.

My plan to work around this is:

1) convert the vector loop into a for loop. *(having a problem here)*
2) have the for loop export each segment of the loop as a wav file instead  of doing what the vector code does which is append it. *(having a problem here)*
3) join each wave file segment using sox.

Most of the examples online go from for loops to vectorized loops not the other way around, any ideas?  I’m also open to other recommendations to fix my memory problem.  Note: I’m working with *1 gig of ram on a rasberry pi 2 and it works and it’s pretty fast*, I’m just trying to get signals with a longer duration, and exporting each segment should allow for this.

I’m using Octave which is compatible with Matlab.

See the working vectorized code below:
Its based off of Paul Nasca stretch algorithm found here
http://www.paulnasca.com/algorithms-created-by-me#TOC-PaulStretch-extreme-sound-stretching-algorithm

```
urlwrite('http://www.onewithall.net/rttmpfiles/3sec8000.wav','3sec8000.wav'); 
inputfn='3sec8000.wav' %change this to test another file
[d, fs, bps]=wavread(inputfn);
inputlen=rows  (d)/fs;

printf ("Original duration of file in seconds = %.2f s\n", rows (d)/fs);

dur=60; %duration / length you want the file to be in seconds
stretch = dur/rows(d)*fs; %how much I need to stretch the file to get it to be the duration I want
windowsize = round (0.25 * fs);

step = round ((windowsize/2)/stretch);

## original window
fwin = @(x) (1-x.^2).^1.25;
win = fwin (linspace (-1, 1, windowsize));

#win = hanning (windowsize)';

## build index
ind = (bsxfun (@plus, 1:windowsize, (0:step:(rows(d)-windowsize))'))';
cols_ind = columns(ind);

## Only use left channel
left_seg = d(:,1)(ind);
clear d ind;

## Apply window
left_seg = bsxfun (@times, left_seg, win');

## FFT
fft_left_seg = fft (left_seg);
clear left_seg

#keyboard

## overwrite phases with random phases
fft_rand_phase_left = fft_left_seg.*exp(i*2*pi*rand(size(fft_left_seg)));
clear fft_left_seg;

ifft_left = ifft (fft_rand_phase_left);
clear fft_rand_phase_left;

## window again
ifft_left = bsxfun (@times, real(ifft_left), win');

## restore the windowed segments with half windowsize shift
restore_step = floor(windowsize/2);
ind2 = (bsxfun (@plus, 1:windowsize, (0:restore_step:(restore_step*(cols_ind-1)))'))';
left_stretched = sparse (ind2(:), repmat(1:columns (ind2), rows(ind2), 1)(:), real(ifft_left(:)), ind2(end, end), cols_ind);
clear ind2 ifft_left win;

left_stretched = full (sum (left_stretched, 2));

## normalize
left_stretched = 0.8 * left_stretched./max(left_stretched);
printf ("converted %s =%.2f(s) file to stretched.wav = %.2f(s)\n", inputfn, inputlen, rows (left_stretched)/fs);
wavwrite (left_stretched, fs, bps, "streched.wav");
```

I tried tracking the problem down by putting in display('line') at key points.  And it looks like the line

```
left_stretched = sparse (ind2(:), repmat(1:columns (ind2), rows(ind2), 1)(:), real(ifft_left(:)), ind2(end, end), cols_ind);
```

The above line seems to have a problem only when I run out of ram.  *It says error subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals.*  please note this only happens when I run out of memory when trying to use long durations by setting dur=60*1800.   If I set dur=60*10 everything works.

Comment: where do you fail in memory? `bsxfun`? `fft`? a minimal working example would be great.

Comment: @bla the code above is a working example it even pulls an audio file from a website to test. I updated the question and added the line at which the issue looks like it starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you remember me? I'm the author of the initial code which you've posted. Below the code as for loop. I've tested this with an output len of 800s.

```
## based on http://hypermammut.sourceforge.net/paulstretch/
## https://github.com/paulnasca/paulstretch_python/blob/master/paulstretch_steps.png

more off
inputfn = "original.wav"
[d, fs, bps] = wavread (inputfn);
inputlen=rows  (d)/fs;

printf ("Original  duration of file in seconds = %.2f s\n", rows (d)/fs);

target_duration = 60; # in seconds
stretch = target_duration/inputlen;
# 1/4 s window len
windowsize = round (0.25 * fs);

# stepwidth between windows
step = round ((windowsize/2)/stretch);
numsteps = floor((rows(d)-windowsize)/step);

## restore the windowed segments with half windowsize shift
restore_step = floor (windowsize / 2);

## stetched duration
stretched_len = (numsteps*restore_step+windowsize)/fs;
printf ("Stretched duration of file in seconds = %.2f s\n", stretched_len);
stretched = zeros (numsteps*restore_step+windowsize, 1);
if (!exist ("out", "dir"))
  mkdir ("out");
endif

## Matrix which holds the freq of the maximum amplitude and the max. amplitude
chunks_stats = zeros (numsteps, 2);

## original window
fwin = @(x) (1-x.^2).^1.25;
win = fwin (linspace (-1, 1, windowsize));

## loop over all windows
for k = 1:numsteps
  if (! mod(k, 50))
    printf ("Calculating chunk %i of %i...\n", k, numsteps);
    fflush (stdout);
  endif

  ## Only use left channel
  s_ind = (k - 1) * step + 1;
  e_ind = s_ind + windowsize - 1;
  tmp = win' .* d(s_ind:e_ind, 1);

  ## FFT, overwrite phases with random phases and IFFT
  tmp = fft(tmp);
  [m, ind] = max (abs(tmp(1:numel(tmp)/2)));
  # Frequency in Hz
  chunks_stats(k, 1) = (ind-1)/windowsize*fs;
  # max Amplitude
  chunks_stats(k, 2) = m;
  printf ("Freq =  %.2f Hz, max = %.2f\n", chunks_stats(k, :));
  tmp = ifft (tmp .* exp(i*2*pi*rand(size(tmp))));

  ## window again
  tmp = win' .* real (tmp);
  fn = sprintf ("out/out_%04i.wav", k);
  wavwrite (tmp, fs, bps, fn);
  s_ind = (k - 1) * restore_step + 1;
  e_ind = s_ind + windowsize - 1;
  stretched (s_ind:e_ind) += tmp;
endfor

## normalize
stretched = 0.8 * stretched./max(stretched);
wavwrite (stretched, fs, bps, "stretched.wav");
```

If you want to write multiple wavs to concatenate them later it's a little bit more difficult because the overlapping windows. But I think this code will run fine on a BeagleBoneBlack.

EDIT: Added saving chunks to separate files and collect maximum amplitude and frequency of this signal per chunk to chunk_stats.

Comment: yes Andy I do remember you and the great code you gave me.  I'll try your answer and see if I can hobble together a way to export each array section as a wave file.  Thanks Again

Comment: What is the reason that you want to export the chunks as wav and concatenate them afterwards?

Comment: I need to analyze each wav file / chunk with fft to get it's frequency, amplitude, and phase (I have this function already).  I place the frequency, amplitude, and phase data of all the files into an array, and based on which frequency, amplitude, and/or phase I choose I concatenate the selected files using sox.

Comment: @RickT: Let me be honest: I doubt you understand the my code or the "paulstretch" algorithm. For example "get the phase" is pointless because it was set to random values. Another point: If you want to analyze every chunk and "place the frequency... into an array" you have the same memory limitation again. If you might explain what you final goal is, I could help better but at this point I'm really depressed helping small steps in the probably wrong direction

Comment: no matter what don't be depressed if you need to stop that's ok, you've done so much to help out already.  Yes some of the code you have at the end I don't fully understand yet, but in time I'll get it.  I should have stated it would be just the frequency, with the largest amplitude, and phase of each wav file that would be placed in the array.  So if I have 1800 individual wave files the array would just be 1800 rows and 3 columns long.  And I would select which ones to concatenate with sox.  My end goal is to analyze vocal patterns in different ways to see if there's a pattern.

Comment: here's a video which I'm basing some of my theories off of.  If it can be done with Parkinson's why not with other issues. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWsehvUkI-c

Comment: @RickT if edited The code above to write the chunks to separate files and collect max Amplitude and matching freq.